# Azure SQL Server Connection failure issue when running SSIS package Jobs

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

**I am facing the following error while loading data on Azure SQL Server:**

First error: Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Communication link failure". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Second error: Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Cannot open server "xyz.com" requested by the login. The login failed.".

Third error: Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login timeout expired". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ".

These errors doesn't occurs continuously but I face it on random basis. Can anyone get me help to resolve this issue as soon as possible as I need to report a solution for the same.

Thanks& Regards, 
Dhara

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you can read as well as we can... presumably.  "Login failed" most likely means the same thing to me as it does to you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate for the following error?    Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: **"Communication link failure"**. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host